# Three queries returning 1 row each

Tags: postgresql

So.. I've got:

**3 DB  Queries returning 1 row each ....**

```
SELECT value FROM ja_settings WHERE varname='clickatel_api_id' 
SELECT value FROM ja_settings WHERE varname='clickatel_user' 
SELECT value FROM ja_settings WHERE varname='clickatel_pass'
```

**Could be re-written as:**

```
SELECT value, 'clickatel_api_id' AS name FROM ja_settings WHERE varname='clickatel_api_id'
UNION ALL
SELECT value, 'clickatel_user' AS name FROM ja_settings WHERE varname='clickatel_user'
UNION ALL
SELECT value, 'clickatel_pass' AS name FROM ja_settings WHERE varname='clickatel_pass' ;
```

1 db query that returns 3 rows ...  (there's even better ways than a union... I know).
This would eliminate 2 db server roundtrips on ALL pages.

How could I write this Query?
Thank you!

Comment: Why would union take three round-trips? Also, using UNION ALL won't guarantee you 3 rows. If you have duplicate results, you will get 4 or more results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess you want something like this:

```
SELECT value, varname
FROM ja_settings 
WHERE varname IN ('clickatel_api_id', 'clickatel_user','clickatel_pass');
```